# How can I share data from a different controller in a laravel view?

Tags: php, oop, laravel

I have a news controller and a pages controller. The pages controller has a method called home, which returns the view for the home page. I want to be able to display this news module on the home page.

From the pages controller, how can I call upon the data from the news controller to display a news module on the front page?

Comment: You might consider doing this a different way. Using partials (small view snippets) to load the news module and just passing the data into the PagesController. Coupling these to each other may prove bad over time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create static method in news controller which returns news items and call it from pages controller, for instance:

```
class PagesController extends BaseController(){

 public function home(){
 $news = NewsController::GetNews();

 return View::make('home')
 ->with('news', $news);
 }
 }

class NewsController extends BaseController(){

public static function GetNews(){
 $news = NewsItem::OrderBy('id', 'DESC')->take(10)->get();
 return $news;
}

 }
```